# how to get on SPFX React onclick funccion

Tags: spfx

I must use on click event. How could I click and fire a javascript function after Cloick Event. Please tell me how could I call this click function. Here is my sample of code:

```
     </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td colspan="3" style="padding-left:93px; "><input type="image" onClick={this.Toggle} src="${require<string>('../toolbox/image/plusv1.png')}" id="plus" alt="PlusImage" style="width:60px; height:60px;" /></td>
      </tr>
        </table>

      </div>
      </div>
  </div>`;
```

Comment: Can you please mention what issues you are facing?

Comment: I can't fire onClick event

Comment: have you tried onClick={this.Toggle()} ?

Comment: Yes but it isnt fire me. it show me allert, but nothing more. if I put var x, Javascript stop firing at all.

Comment: After this I have got: [1566990483681][OtherGlobalError.window.onerro] TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'Toggle'
sp-loader-assembly_default.js (9587,13)

0: Object doesn't support property or method 'Toggle'

Comment: debug the script and check if there is any Toggle function available in "this"

Comment: Yes there is:   public Toggle(){

    alert('Skrypt odpalony');
    alert('Drugie okno');
   // var x = document.getElementById("extend1");
   // if (x.style.display === "none") {
    //  x.style.display = "block";
   // } else {
   //   x.style.display = "none";
   // }
  }

Comment: Do you see the Toggle function when you debug and type "this." ?

Comment: Where should I type "this"?

Comment: On debugging. Check how to debug SPFx and try it. We should avoid avoid too many comments here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code after rendering the JSX element/ HTML :

```
document.getElementById("Element ID").onclick = () => this.Toggle();
```